# Configuring two ELB instances that points to one ALB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-ec2, vert.x

Previously I had one instance in ELB that points to one ALB. Now, I need to add an extra instance to my existing ELB.
Is there a best way to configure two ELB instances that points to one ALB?
My configuration so far is 
Two instances of ELBs points to one instance of ALB on port 7070.
Sticky session is upto 10 mins
With this configuration application error is seen.

I also have attached the error log below. When I rolled back ALB to ELB, this log didn't appear.Is it the configuration issue of ALB or something else.[image]

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.